# JavaScript Insert table into text editor with out plugins (don't suggest plugins)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to insert an generated table inside the WYSIWYG text editor document with sample code.
I saw so many plugins, I have only basic knowledge in JavaScript. Now I don't want to use plugins. With normal JavaScript code, I need to insert an table inside the WYSIWYG text editor based on cursor position.

I have sample [**Main FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/f7gpnh4n/28/) for bold, italic, underline functionalities using "execCommand". **First three fields in popover are mandatory**

Now I need to add one button for table and on click of that I need to show one popover for table info, which is mentioned in below table generator code. And I need to show the result in I-Frame. As of now I am showing the result inside the generated div only.

Is there any way to insert table inside the WYSIWYG editor with our own functionality. I have sample code for table generator
**From this table generator "What ever I am getting on click of generate table button" should be shown inside the text editor.**

Can anyone Help on this.
Below code is sample.

**Note:
You can suggest your's own way with out plugins like CKEditor , TinyMCV**

**Thanks in Adavnce**

```js
$('.wysiwyg-controls a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false);
});


//# region for popover open and close

$(function(){
    $("#popoverExampleTwo").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
          return $('#popoverExampleTwoHiddenContent').html();
        },
        trigger:'click',
        title: '',
        placement:'bottom'
    });
    
});    
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  if (typeof $(e.target).data('original-title') == 'undefined' &&
     !$(e.target).parents().is('.popover.in')) {
    $('[data-original-title]').popover('hide');
      $('.popover').css('display','none');
  }
});

$(document).on("click", "#button_cells", function() {
    generateTable();
});

function generateTable(){
 var myRows = document.getElementById("rows");
var myColumns = document.getElementById("columns");
var tableSummary = document.getElementById("table_summary");
var tableCaption = document.getElementById("table_caption");
var tableClass = document.getElementById("table_class");
var tableID = document.getElementById("table_id");
var cellsSubmit = document.getElementById("button_cells");
var numberPattern = /^(\(\d+\) ?)?(\d+[\- ])*\d+$/;
var cellsHolder = document.getElementById("cells_holder");
var buttonGenerateHolder = document.getElementById("button_generate_holder");
var myColumnsHTML = "";
var myRowsHTML = "";
var myTHCheckbox = document.forms["table_generator_form"]["TH"];
var codeResultHolder = document.getElementById("code_result");
var codeResult = document.getElementById("code_result_text");
var myFinalHTML = "";
var myTextAreaID = 1;
var THDone = 0;
var THFinal = "";
var tableClassValue = "";
var tableIDValue = "";
var myRadioValue = "";
var myRadioNone = document.getElementById("th_none");
var myRadioRow = document.getElementById("th_row");
var myRadioColumn = document.getElementById("th_column");
var myTableExtrasHolder = document.getElementById("table_extras_holder");
var myTableExtrasCheckbox = document.forms["table_generator_form"]["table_extras"];
var numericPattern = /\d/;
var myTab = "";

  myColumnsHTML = "";
 myTextAreaID = 1;
 
 if (myRows.value == "" || /^\s+$/.test(myRows.value))
  {
  //alert("Please enter number of Rows");
  return false;
  }

 if (numberPattern.test(myRows.value) == false || myRows.value > 50)
  {
  //alert('Only numeric data below 50 allowed for Rows');
  return false;
  }

 if (myColumns.value == "" || /^\s+$/.test(myColumns.value))
  {
  //alert("Please enter number of Columns");
  return false;
  }

 if (numberPattern.test(myColumns.value) == false || myColumns.value > 11)
  {
  //alert('Only numeric data below 12 allowed for Columns');
  return false;
  }

 if (tableSummary.value == "" || /^\s+$/.test(tableSummary.value))
  {
  //alert("Please enter a Summary for your table");
  return false;
  }

  for (r=0;r<myRows.value;r++)
  {
   for (c=0;c<myColumns.value;c++) 
   {
    myColumnsHTML += "<textarea rows='5' cols='15' id='text_box"+myTextAreaID+"'></textarea>";
    if(c+1 == myColumns.value) {
     myColumnsHTML = myColumnsHTML + "<br />";
    }
    myTextAreaID = myTextAreaID + 1;
   }
  }

 cellsHolder.innerHTML = myColumnsHTML;
}   
    
$(document).on("click", "#button_generate", function() {
    generateTableCode();
});

function generateTableCode(){
    var myRows = document.getElementById("rows");
var myColumns = document.getElementById("columns");
var tableSummary = document.getElementById("table_summary");
var tableCaption = document.getElementById("table_caption");
var tableClass = document.getElementById("table_class");
var tableID = document.getElementById("table_id");
var cellsSubmit = document.getElementById("button_cells");
var numberPattern = /^(\(\d+\) ?)?(\d+[\- ])*\d+$/;
var cellsHolder = document.getElementById("cells_holder");
var buttonGenerateHolder = document.getElementById("button_generate_holder");
var myColumnsHTML = "";
var myRowsHTML = "";
var myTHCheckbox = document.forms["table_generator_form"]["TH"];
var codeResultHolder = document.getElementById("code_result");
var codeResult = document.getElementById("code_result_text");
var myFinalHTML = "";
var myTextAreaID = 1;
var THDone = 0;
var THFinal = "";
var tableClassValue = "";
var tableIDValue = "";
var myRadioValue = "";
var myRadioNone = document.getElementById("th_none");
var myRadioRow = document.getElementById("th_row");
var myRadioColumn = document.getElementById("th_column");
var myTableExtrasHolder = document.getElementById("table_extras_holder");
var myTableExtrasCheckbox = document.forms["table_generator_form"]["table_extras"];
var numericPattern = /\d/;
var myTab = "";

  myColumnsHTML = "";
 myTextAreaID = 1;

 
 if (tableSummary.value == "" || /^\s+$/.test(tableSummary.value))
  {
  //alert("Table Summary is required");
  return false;
  }

 if (tableID.value.indexOf(" ") !== -1)
  {
  //alert("You cannot use a space in the Table ID");
  return false;
  }

 if (numericPattern.test(tableID.value.charAt("0")) == true)
  {
  //alert("The Table ID cannot begin with a numeric character");
  return false;
  }

 for (var z=0; z < myTHCheckbox.length; z++) {
 if (myTHCheckbox[z].checked)
  {
   myRadioValue = myTHCheckbox[z].value;
  }
 }

 codeResult.value = "";
 THDone = 0;
 THFinal = "";
 tableClassValue = "";
 tableIDValue = "";

 if (tableClass.value !== "") {
  tableClassValue = " class=\""+tableClass.value+"\"";
 }

 if (tableID.value !== "") {
  tableIDValue = " id=\""+tableID.value+"\"";
 }
 
 myFinalHTML = "<table cellspacing=\"0\" summary=\""+tableSummary.value+"\""+tableClassValue+tableIDValue+">\n";
 
 if (tableCaption.value !== "") {
 myFinalHTML += " <caption>"+tableCaption.value+"</caption>\n";
 }
 var myIncrement = 1;
  for (r2=0;r2<myRows.value;r2++)
  {
   if (r2==0 && myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked) {
   myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + " <thead>\n  <tr>\n";
   }
   else
   {
   
    if (r2==myRows.value - 1 && myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked) {
    myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + " </tbody>\n <tfoot>\n  <tr>\n";
    }
    else
    {
    myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + " " + myTab + "<tr>\n";
    }

   }
   
   for (c2=0;c2<myColumns.value;c2++) 
   {
    if (myRadioValue=="th_row_selected" && c2 < myColumns.value && THDone < myColumns.value + 1 && THFinal == "") {
     myFinalHTML += "  " + myTab + "<th>"+document.getElementById("text_box"+myIncrement).value+"</th>\n";
     THDone = THDone + 1;
     myIncrement = myIncrement + 1;
     if (THDone == myColumns.value) {
      THFinal = "end";
     }
    }
    else
    {
    if (c2==0 && myRadioValue=="th_column_selected") {
     myFinalHTML += "  " + myTab + "<th>"+document.getElementById("text_box"+myIncrement).value+"</th>\n";
     myIncrement = myIncrement + 1;
     }
     else
     {
    myFinalHTML += "  " + myTab + "<td>"+document.getElementById("text_box"+myIncrement).value+"</td>\n";
    myIncrement = myIncrement + 1;
    }
    }
  }

   if (r2==0 && myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked) {
   myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + "  </tr>\n </thead>\n <tbody>\n";
   }
   else
   {
   if (r2==myRows.value - 1 && myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked) {
   myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + "  </tr>\n </tfoot>\n";
   }
   else
   {
   myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + " " + myTab + "</tr>\n";
   }
   }
   
  }

  myFinalHTML = myFinalHTML + "</table>";

  //makeOpacityZero(codeResult.id);
  codeResult.value = myFinalHTML;
  //opacity(codeResult.id, 0, 100, 400);
  myTab = "";
}

//$(document).on("click", "#code_result_text", function() {
  //  this.select();
//});

//$(document).on("click", "#th_row", function() {
   // myTableExtrasHolder.style.display = "block";
//});


//$(document).on("click", "#th_none", function() {
  // myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked = false;
  //myTableExtrasHolder.style.display = "none";
//});

//myRadioColumn.onclick = function() {
  //myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked = false;
  //myTableExtrasHolder.style.display = "none";
 //}
 
 //myTableExtrasCheckbox.onclick = function () {
  //if (myTableExtrasCheckbox.checked && myRows.value < 3) {
  // alert('You must have more than 2 rows in order to have a TBODY');
  // return false;
  //}
 //}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wysiwyg-editor {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}

.wysiwyg-controls {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #C2CACF;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.wysiwyg-controls a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ADB5B9;
}
.wysiwyg-controls [data-role="bold"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.wysiwyg-controls [data-role="italic"] {
  font-style: italic;
}
.wysiwyg-controls [data-role="underline"] {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

[class^="menu"], [class^="menu"]:before, [class^="menu"]:after {
  position: relative;
  top: 48%;
  display: block;
  width: 65%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ADB5B9;
}
[class^="menu"]:before {
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  width: 80%;
}
[class^="menu"]:after {
  content: '';
  top: 3px;
  width: 80%;
}

.menu-left:before, .menu-left:after {
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.menu-right:before, .menu-right:after {
  margin-left: 4px;
}

.wysiwyg-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #C2CACF;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  background: #F2F4F6;
}

textarea{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wysiwyg-editor">
  <div class="wysiwyg-controls">
    <a href='#' data-role='bold'>B</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='italic'>I</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='underline'>U</a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifyleft'><i class="menu-left"></i></a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifycenter'><i class="menu-center"></i></a>
    <a href='#' data-role='justifyright'><i class="menu-right"></i></a>
      <input type="button" id="popoverExampleTwo" value="table"/>
  </div>
  <div class="wysiwyg-content" contenteditable>
    <b>Let's make a statement!</b>
    <br>
    <i>This is an italicised sentence.</i>
    <br>
    <u>Very important information.</u>
  </div>

      <div id="popoverExampleTwoHiddenContent" style="display: none">
      
      <form id="table_generator_form" action="http://www.impressivewebs.com/html-table-code-generator/index.html" method="get">

<h1>HTML Table Code Generator 2.0</h1>

 <div>
 <label for="rows">Number of Rows:</label> <input type="text" id="rows" size="2" maxlength="2" class="txt">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="columns">Number of Columns:</label> <input type="text" id="columns" size="2" maxlength="2" class="txt">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="table_summary">Table Summary: (for screen readers)</label> <input type="text" id="table_summary" class="txt">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="table_caption">Table Caption: (optional)</label> <input type="text" id="table_caption" class="txt">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="table_class">CSS Class Name for Table: (optional)</label> <input type="text" id="table_class" class="txt">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="table_id">CSS ID for Table: (optional)</label> <input type="text" id="table_id" class="txt">
 </div>

 <div>
 <label for="th_none">No &lt;th&gt;</label> <input type="radio" name="TH" id="th_none" value="th_none_selected" class="checkbox" checked="checked">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="th_row">First row as &lt;th&gt;</label> <input type="radio" name="TH" id="th_row" value="th_row_selected" class="checkbox"> 
 </div>
 
 <div id="table_extras_holder">
 <label for="table_extras">Include &lt;tbody&gt;, &lt;thead&gt;, &amp; &lt;tfoot&gt; </label> <input type="checkbox" name="table_extras" id="table_extras" value="table_extras_selected"> 
 </div>

 <div>
 <label for="th_column">First column as &lt;th&gt;</label> <input type="radio" name="TH" id="th_column" value="th_column_selected" class="checkbox">
 </div>
 
 <div id="button_cells_holder"><input type="button" id="button_cells" value="Prepare Cells for Data Insertion"></div>
 
 <div id="cells_holder"></div><!-- cells holder ends -->

 <div id="button_generate_holder"><input type="button" id="button_generate" value="Generate Table Code"></div>
 
 <div id="code_result"><textarea rows="25" cols="70" id="code_result_text"></textarea></div>
</form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a line to your html to host the tableview:

```
<div id="table_result"><iframe id="tableView"></iframe></div>
```

Then add this javascript line to your "Generate Table Code" button click event:

```
$('#tableView').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = $('#code_result_text').value
```

This will copy the already prepared table html code from the `code_result_text` textarea into the new `iframe` as actual innerHTML.

Comment: I need to attach that code to inside the editor not inside the popup. Please check my sample code(updated) , whatever I am displaying inside the popover after click of button(prepare cells for data insertion) should show inside the editor. Please have a look and help me. There is a problem with "Generate Table code" button click action.

Comment: Your updated code does not work even here in Fiddle, while the original did. I prepared the solution for the original so please rate accordingly. I will look into your new code later.

Comment: can you check now. fiddle link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/f7gpnh4n/28/)**bold**. First 3 fields are mandatory.

Comment: Now try this: `$('.wysiwyg-content')[0].innerHTML = $('.wysiwyg-content')[0].innerHTML.concat( $('#code_result_text')[0].value )`
This will append the generated table html code in `code_result_text` into the wysiwyg editor content by class `wysiwyg-content`.

Comment: By the way you still need to put that line into the end of the `generateTableCode` function, after the line `codeResult.value = myFinalHTML;` (somewhere around line 260).

Comment: @vascora: Thanks man I got solution with your reference.  Please update this fiddle from your side. I got solution with your reference.[ Solution Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/f7gpnh4n/33/)

Comment: @vascora: Thanks for your reference . I got solution with your reference.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/f7gpnh4n/33/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94606/discussion-between-rayudu-and-vacsora).

Comment: Glad to help, please remember to kindly update your green answer tick accordingly.